# "Fields" in tinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce

When editing a document in MS Word, you can insert a `field' and then insert references to it. When the field's value is changed, you can just update the values in references without editing them manually.

Is there similar functionality available in tinyMCE, for example via a 3rd party plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrote my own plugin in the end and it turned out quite well.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there is no such plugin available.
But it cannot be that difficult to implement this functionality in a custom tinymce plugin.

Comment: > implement this functionality in a custom tinymce plugin I was about to start doing that. Just wanted to know if there were any existing solutions. I dont like reinventing wheels :)

Comment: thats the way to go, i'd do the same: ask first and if nothing is available do it myself